# Prevent Firefox from handling keypress using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm listening to different key presses in my application using the snippet below, which works well. There are however a number of keys bound in Firefox to internal actions (such as pressing '/' which triggers the Quickfind feature).

I would like to prevent Firefox from triggering this feature using Javascript in my application. This should be possible since in Gmail pressing '/' leads to focussing of the search field.

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if (e.code === 'KeyF') {
    // Perform logic
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.
You add list Code need disable into array.

```js
 window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
                                // space and arrow keys
                                if ([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                }
                            }, false);
```